# Min and max of a two variable function

Tags: calculus

This is not more like a question,more like a solution estimation.The problem is :find the local min and max of the function $x^2+y^2-12x+16y$ if $x^2+y^2 \le 25$.Here is my solution:first I use Lagrange multipliers and find two lambads as a solution -3,1 then I find two couples $(x,y)$ and find min and max answer.But I am not done.I see that if I test other $(x,y)$ I get bigger max that the one from Lagrange so I estimate that x,y are both in the interval $[-5,5]$ and find the local max and min of each x and y respectively in the interval $[-5;5]$ .Now from Lagrange and using the derivatives I just mention for x and y respectively I get the max and min and in which points it is achieved.

Now the problem is that for this solution I got only 2/10 points because I didn't use Vaershtrats.Now tell me is this a reason to get so low points?, because I think from the fact that I saw that there is bigger max than Lagrange  by inputing random numbers I decided to check for local max/min.

$f_{x} = 2x-12$, $f_{y}=2y-16$ ,now if we look at the derivative of $x^2+y^2-25$ we get $f_{1_{x}}$ =$2x$ and $f_{1_{y}}$ =$2y$,then we must have 
$2x-12=\lambda .2x$ and $2y-16=\lambda.2y$ then I get that lambda must be -1 or 3 and I get two solutions (-3,4) and (3,-4) and plug them in the original,but I also do

$f_{x} > 0 $ where x is in $[-5;5]$ and fin the local max/min,evauluate the solutions and plug them in and see my results,the same for
 $f_{y}>0$ where y is $[-5,5]$ .Now from these 3 cases I evaluate the max/min and it is clearly in the points (-3,4), (3,-4) because there we get the lowest and the highest values

The problem is Lagrange is used when the constraint is with = but here we have inequality $(x^2+y^2 \le 25)$,however I checked the local max and mins and there shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: would be great if you write down your approach analytically.

Comment: Okey just a second

Comment: The maximizing pair should be $(-3,4)$, this results in a max value of 125 for your function.

Comment: yes I got the answer it is (-3,4) and (3,-4) on my paper

Comment: the minimizing pair is (3,-4) and the result of the function is $$-75$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes but in the $x^2+y^2<25$ case is my work with derivatives enough to cover that case?

Answer (score 1):

Would a purely geometrical argument be sufficient, or does it have to be done using Lagrange multipliers?

The constraint $x^2+y^2\leq25$ indicates all point on or in the circle centre O radius 5

Let $f=x^2+y^2-12x+16y$

Then the quantity $f+100=r^2$ represents the squared radius of any circle centred at $(6,-8)$ with radius $r$.

A diagram showing possible circles touching indicates that $\max r=15$ and $\min r=5$, and hence $$-75\leq f\leq125$$